# Action bar not visible in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar

I used a custom toolbar in one of my activities by setting the *theme* of that activity to *No Action Bar* in the *Android Manifest* file.

```
<activity android:name=".ChatLogActivity"
              android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
              android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    >
```

But now rest all the activities are showing *no action bar* in the Android Studio at the time of designing which is making the whole designing process cumbersome. However, the *action bar* is showing up in the phone in all those activities. I tried doing *"Invalidate cache and restart"* but the problem still persists. I can't understand why is it happening.

**Screenshots**
[image]

[image]

**EDIT 1: Theme is already set to *Dark action bar* in the design tab**
[image]

**P.S: I know the UI is an eyesore**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this only in the preview? If so, just turn on 'Show Layout Decorations' in the preview tab of your layout file.

Android Studio v3.4.1
[image]

Answer (score 3):

This has changed with the latest versions of Android Studio IDE

**Android Studio V4.1.1**

[image]

[image]

[image]